# How to use MySQL to create view that selects an ID by the nearest price by timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a view with `block.ID`, `block.timestamp`, `historic.USD`, but I only want to select the first nearest `USD` value by `timestamp` to match a block `ID`.

`block` table:

```
| ID | timestamp              |
|  0 |  2013-08-22 00:38:05   |
|  1 |  2013-08-22 00:37:53   |
```

`historic` table:

```
| timestamp             | USD |
|  2013-08-22 00:37:53  | 800 |
|  2013-08-22 00:38:30  | 799 |
|  2013-08-22 00:40:53  | 789 |
```

So far my query is:

```
CREATE VIEW block_pricing 
AS 
SELECT block.id, block.timestamp, historic.usd 
FROM block, historic 
WHERE block.timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(historic.timestamp);
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify, block.ID should not be repeated. It should match with its closet historic pricing

Comment: Should somehow be joining those tables...

Comment: i did think about it.  But this query is a bit tricky and dont know how to approach it.

Comment: How do you know which rows from the `historic` table belong to which `block`? What if the `historic` table contains rows for different blocks?

Comment: should only select one historic value to match a block, and that historic timestamp must be closet to block timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW block_pricing 
AS 
SELECT block.id,min(block.timestamp)timestamp, historic.usd 
FROM block, historic 
WHERE block.timestamp <= historic.timestamp
GROUP BY id;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/8)

Comment: gd try, but block.ID should not be repeated :/

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54afc/7 ,i hope one of these answers can help you.

Comment: thanks the first one in it worked out.  Will it be possible to speed up the query?  i have a set of 400K blocks

Comment: When you use `Group` on big data, it cause to make query so slow,and i don't know the way which make it faster.